# Express - can't serve static files (404 error)

Tags: node.js, express

I came across many questions like these but it doesn't look like I'm doing anything wrong. The problem is that I can't get my static files to load.

**Folder structure:**

```
/client
    index.html
    /assets
        /css
            main.css
/server
    app.js
```

**app.js:**

```
var assetsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../client/assets');
app.use(express.static('assetsPath'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/' + 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('\nListening on port 8080!');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Yet when loading the page in the browser, I get 404 on `http://localhost:8080/css/main.css`

Is there anything missing?

Thank you!

*PS: using express ^4.13.4 & node v5.10.1*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got a typo in your express.static() function.

```
var assetsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../client/assets');
app.use(express.static('assetsPath'));
```

should be

```
var assetsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../client/assets');
app.use(express.static(assetsPath));
```

Comment: Ok, so this was one of those moments... 
Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is facing a similar issue, but it doesn't work even after fixing, be sure to clear your browser data (and cache) at least for the time since the problem occurred. For me, a permanent redirect was causing the browser to repeatedly return 404, even though I fixed the express code

Answer (score 3):

`express.static` accepts path to static files, so you can simplify with following line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/assets')));
```